# Why does nuxt give me this error with vue-chartjs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, charts, vuejs2, chart.js

### I get this error while trying to make vue-chartjs work

```
 WARN  in ./node_modules/vue-chartjs/es/BaseCharts.js

"export 'default' (imported as 'Chart') was not found in 'chart.js'
```

And also this in devtools:

```
TypeError: chart_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.default is not a constructor
```

### Steps to recreate:

1. Create nuxt app with: `$ yarn create nuxt-app <project_name>`
2. Add vue-chartjs with `$ yarn add vue-chartjs chart.js`
3. Add following code which should work according to vue-chartjs docs

~/components/BarChart.js

```
import { Bar } from 'vue-chartjs'

export default {
  extends: Bar,
  props: ['data', 'options'],
  mounted() {
    this.renderChart(this.data, this.options)
  },
}
```

~/pages/index.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <div>
      <bar-chart
        :data="barChartData"
        :options="barChartOptions"
        :height="200"
      />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      barChartData: {
        labels: [
          '2019-06',
          '2019-07',
          '2019-08',
          '2019-09',
          '2019-10',
          '2019-11',
          '2019-12',
          '2020-01',
          '2020-02',
          '2020-03',
          '2020-04',
          '2020-05',
        ],
        datasets: [
          {
            label: 'Visits',
            data: [10, 15, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 34, 45, 11, 78, 45],
            backgroundColor: '#003f5c',
          },
          {
            label: 'Pages Views',
            data: [30, 24, 57, 23, 68, 72, 25, 64, 133, 143, 165, 33, 56],
            backgroundColor: '#2f4b7c',
          },
          {
            label: 'Users',
            data: [45, 65, 30, 53, 34, 35, 26, 37, 34, 45, 67, 87, 98],
            backgroundColor: '#665191',
          },
        ],
      },
      barChartOptions: {
        responsive: true,
        legend: {
          display: false,
        },
        title: {
          display: true,
          text: 'Google analytics data',
          fontSize: 24,
          fontColor: '#6b7280',
        },
        tooltips: {
          backgroundColor: '#17BF62',
        },
        scales: {
          xAxes: [
            {
              gridLines: {
                display: false,
              },
            },
          ],
          yAxes: [
            {
              ticks: {
                beginAtZero: true,
              },
              gridLines: {
                display: false,
              },
            },
          ],
        },
      },
    }
  },
}
</script>

<style>
/* Sample `apply` at-rules with Tailwind CSS
.container {
@apply min-h-screen flex justify-center items-center text-center mx-auto;
}
*/
.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.title {
  font-family: 'Quicksand', 'Source Sans Pro', -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont,
    'Segoe UI', Roboto, 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, sans-serif;
  display: block;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 100px;
  color: #35495e;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.subtitle {
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 42px;
  color: #526488;
  word-spacing: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}

.links {
  padding-top: 15px;
}
</style>
```

I am also using tailwindcss in the project and other nuxt project options were Axios, Git, ESlint, Prettier.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Chart.js has a new release version with 3.0.x. I think, `vue-chartjs` does not support it yet.

You can downgrade chart.js and try again.

ChartJS [3.0.1 - Published 2 days ago]
https://www.npmjs.com/package/chart.js?activeTab=readme

And there is a `vue-chartjs` issue about 22 hours ago.
https://github.com/apertureless/vue-chartjs/issues/695

Comment: Thank you, that's a nice catch! Can't believe I actually just started using chart.js in vue and this happened on my first try when the release is just 2 days old.

Answer (score 41):

chart.js version above 3.0.0 is not compatible, you need to downgrade chart.js
`npm install chart.js@2.9.4`

This has solved my issue

Answer (score 15):

maybe its a bit late but I have to give the answer,

what you need is to change the version of both libraries

```
npm install chart.js@2.7.1 vue-chartjs@3.4.0 --save
```

it works fine in vue2

Comment: This helped me a lot, thank you

Answer (score 6):

```
yarn add vue-chartjs chart.js@2.9.4
```

if you are using yarn