# Syntax error : Cannot use import statement outside a module in Vue2 chart js

Tags: vuejs2, chart.js, nuxt.js

Using version)
Vue2     : 2.6.14,
chart.js : 2.9.4,
vue-chartjs : 4.1.0,
nuxtjs/vuetify: 1.12.3

components\BarChart.vue

```
<template>
  <Bar
    :chart-options="chartOptions"
    :chart-data="chartData"
    :chart-id="chartId"
    :dataset-id-key="datasetIdKey"
    :plugins="plugins"
    :css-classes="cssClasses"
    :styles="styles"
    :width="width"
    :height="height"
  />
</template>

<script type="module">
import { Chart as ChartJS, Title, Tooltip, Legend, BarElement, CategoryScale, LinearScale } from 'chart.js'
ChartJS.register(Title, Tooltip, Legend, BarElement, CategoryScale, LinearScale)
import { Bar } from 'vue-chartjs/legacy'

export default {
  name: 'BarChart',
  components: { Bar },
  props: {
    chartId: {
      type: String,
      default: 'bar-chart'
    },
    datasetIdKey: {
      type: String,
      default: 'label'
    },
    width: {
      type: Number,
      default: 400
    },
    height: {
      type: Number,
      default: 400
    },
    cssClasses: {
      default: '',
      type: String
    },
    styles: {
      type: Object,
      default: () => {}
    },
    plugins: {
      type: Object,
      default: () => {}
    },
    chartData: {
      labels: [ 'January', 'February', 'March' ],
      datasets: [ { data: [40, 20, 12] } ]
    },
    chartOptions: {
      responsive: true
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

When try "npm run dev"
**Syntax error : Cannot use import statement outside a module** has occurred

When install chart.js 3.7.1 version and change code

```
import { Chart as ChartJS, Title, Tooltip, Legend, BarElement, CategoryScale, LinearScale } from 'chart.js/auto'
```

has same error.

What should I do..?

Comment: Both imports are wrong, V2 has no treeshaking and thus no named exports, it only exports the default chart. For v3 the auto package also does not provide any named exports only the default one

Comment: Finally I solve it. Delete below code and referece this URL.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66940954/why-does-nuxt-give-me-this-error-with-vue-chartjs

`
import { Chart as ChartJS, Title, Tooltip, Legend, BarElement, CategoryScale, LinearScale } from 'chart.js'
ChartJS.register(Title, Tooltip, Legend, BarElement, CategoryScale, LinearScale)
`

Comment: Feel free to post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I solve it. Delete below code and referece this URL.
[Why does nuxt give me this error with vue-chartjs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66940954/why-does-nuxt-give-me-this-error-with-vue-chartjs)

```js
import { Chart as ChartJS, Title, Tooltip, Legend, BarElement, CategoryScale, LinearScale } from 'chart.js' ChartJS.register(Title, Tooltip, Legend, BarElement, CategoryScale, LinearScale)
```